# How do I dispatch two different properties to the selector?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a `selector` that is dependent on another one, which they need the userId to be able to "work".

But now I would like to create a selector that receives the "`userId`" and also receives another property called "`userFriend`".

What happens is that he is complaining about this parameter pass, as he is only finding one property, which is the "`userId`".

**ERROR 1:**

```
Property 'userFriend' does not exist on type '{ userId: any; }'
```

**ERROR 2:**

```
TS2339: Property 'userFriend' does not exist on type '{userId: any; } '.

34 (latestReadMessages, totalUnreadMessages, {userId, userFriend}) => {
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
src / app / services / store / chat / chat-selectors.service.ts: 34: 26 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 8, '(mapFn: (state: object, props: {userId: any;}) => IChatFriendLatestMessageList, props ?: {userId: any;}): (source $: Observable <object>) => Observable <...> ', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{userId: string; userFriend: IUser; } 'is not assignable to parameter of type' {userId: any; } '.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userFriend' does not exist in type '{userId: any; } '.
  Overload 2 of 8, '(key1: "user" | "chat", key2: "loading" | "data" | "dataError" | "ids" | "entities"): (source $: Observable <IStoreState>) = > Observable <any> ', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'MemoizedSelectorWithProps <object, {userId: any; }, IChatFriendLatestMessageList, DefaultProjectorFn <IChatFriendLatestMessageList>> 'is not assignable to parameter of type' "user" | "chat" '.
      Type 'MemoizedSelectorWithProps <object, {userId: any; }, IChatFriendLatestMessageList, DefaultProjectorFn <IChatFriendLatestMessageList>> 'is not assignable to type' "chat" '.

34 return this.store.pipe (select (selector.getFriendLatestMessageList, {userId, userFriend}));
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**SELECTORS:**

```
export const messagesById = createSelector(selectAll, (chat: IChat[], { userId }) => {
  let messageIndex = 0;
  return chat.map((props, index) => {
    if (props.id === userId) {
      messageIndex = index;
      return props.messages;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  })[messageIndex];
});

export const isLoading = createSelector(FEATURE_SELECTOR, ({ loading }) => loading);
export const error = createSelector(FEATURE_SELECTOR, ({ dataError }) => dataError);
export const friendMessages = createSelector(messagesById, messages => messages.filter(msg => !msg.isMain));
export const friendLatestMessage = createSelector(friendMessages, messages => messages[messages.length - 1]);
export const friendLatestReadMessages = createSelector(friendMessages, messages => messages.filter(msg => msg.isRead));
export const friendLatestUnreadMessages = createSelector(friendMessages, messages =>
  messages.filter(msg => !msg.isRead)
);
export const totalUnreadMessagesFriend = createSelector(friendLatestUnreadMessages, messages => messages.length);

export const getFriendLatestMessageList = createSelector(
  friendLatestMessage,
  totalUnreadMessagesFriend,

  (latestReadMessages, totalUnreadMessages, { userId, userFriend }) => {
    const latestMessageList: IChatFriendLatestMessageList = {
      user: userFriend.id,
      informations: {
        chatMessage: [latestReadMessages],
        isNewLastMessage: !userFriend.isClicked && totalUnreadMessages > 0,
        total: totalUnreadMessages,
      },
    };

    return latestMessageList;
  }
);
```

**SERVICE FOR DISPATCH SELECTORS:**

```
getFriendLatestMessageListById(userId: string, user: IUser): Observable<IChatFriendLatestMessageList> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(selector.getFriendLatestMessageList, { userId, user }));
}
```

**INTERFACE:**

```
export interface IChatFriendLatestMessageList {
    userFriend: IUser;
    informations: {
        chatMessage: IChatMessage[];
        isNewLastMessage: boolean;
        total: number;
    };
}
```

**ERROR SCREENSHOT**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because this selector has own props and in the same time it uses parent selectors that also have own props.

NGRX doesn't support it and to make it working we need to incapsulate the parent selectors.

```js
export const getFriendLatestMessageList = createSelector(
    s => s, // selecting the whole store.
    (store, { userId, userFriend }) => {
        // selecting our state.
        const latestReadMessages = friendLatestMessage(store, { userId });
        const totalUnreadMessages = totalUnreadMessagesFriend(store, { userId });
        // using them.
        const latestMessageList: IChatFriendLatestMessageList = {
            user: userFriend,
            informations: {
                chatMessage: [latestReadMessages],
                isNewLastMessage: !userFriend.isClicked && totalUnreadMessages > 0,
                total: totalUnreadMessages,
            },
        };

        return latestMessageList;
    }
);
```

Comment: It was well noticed, but the error prevails, I inserted the error in my question

Comment: please share `IChatFriendLatestMessageList`, Looks like you need to add there `userFriend`.

Comment: also have you tried with `: {userId: any; userFriend: IUser}`?

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the dispatch of the selector, and then it arrives at the selector, it does not recognize the second property. I don't know if ngrx accepts more than two properties, since I already use the userId inside the selector that is in conjunction with the one mentioned above.

Comment: it accepts only one property, but to pass there `{userId: value, userFriend: user}` is fine.

Comment: Might you share a screenshot of the error when you define types? I should work, perhaps it needs time to recheck errors: https://take.ms/mHEw4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214899/discussion-between-satantime-and-thiago-de-bonis).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the function param

```
getFriendLatestMessageListById(userId: string, userFriend: IUser): Observable<IChatFriendLatestMessageList> {
  return this.store.pipe(select(selector.getFriendLatestMessageList, { userId, userFriend}));
}
```

Comment: It was well noticed, but the error prevails, I inserted the error in my question